# django check email address is live or not

Tags: django, email, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a django project and need to verify email address is live.

Suppose a user send registration request with email - **pankajsharma00008@gmail.com** it will check if this email is registered on gmail or not. Here it is not only for gmail but it can be any email service provider like Yahoo, hotmail, etc.

There are thousands of email service providers, how can I check if email address is registered on that mail service. Is there any app for django to check valid mails?

Answer (score 2):

You can't check directly with the email provider.The thing to do is to send a confirmation link to that address with a link to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for reply, tell me when I tried to register on some sites with random email address or not valid email then how they caught me and raise error - **This email is not vaid** how ?

Comment: @PankajSharma They simply have a list of blacklisted domain names (such as example.com, mailinator.com etc) which are either not supposed to have valid email addresses or disposable email services.

Answer (score 2):

First, validate domain and email is valid

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email
try:
    validate_email(username)
    valid_email = True
except validate_email.ValidationError:
    valid_email = False
```

Then validate domain, not in this list

```
0815.ru
0815.ru0clickemail.com
0815.ry
0815.su
0845.ru
0clickemail.com
0-mail.com
0wnd.net
0wnd.org
10mail.com
10mail.org
10minut.com.pl
10minutemail.cf
10minutemail.co.za
10minutemail.com
10minutemail.de
10minutemail.ga
10minutemail.gq
10minutemail.ml
10minutemail.net
10minutesmail.com
10x9.com
123-m.com
126.com
12houremail.com
12minutemail.com
12minutemail.net
139.com
163.com
1ce.us
1chuan.com
1fsdfdsfsdf.tk
1mail.ml
1pad.de
1zhuan.com
20mail.it
20minutemail.com
21cn.com
24hourmail.com
2fdgdfgdfgdf.tk
2prong.com
30minutemail.com
33mail.com
3d-painting.com
3mail.ga
3trtretgfrfe.tk
420blaze.it
4gfdsgfdgfd.tk
4mail.cf
4mail.ga
4warding.com
4warding.net
4warding.org
5ghgfhfghfgh.tk
5mail.cf
5mail.ga
60minutemail.com
675hosting.com
675hosting.net
675hosting.org
6hjgjhgkilkj.tk
6ip.us
6mail.cf
6mail.ga
6mail.ml
6paq.com
6url.com
75hosting.com
75hosting.net
75hosting.org
7days-printing.com
7mail.ga
7mail.ml
7tags.com
8127ep.com
8chan.co
8mail.cf
8mail.ga
8mail.ml
99experts.com
9mail.cf
9ox.net
a.mailcker.com
a.vztc.com
a45.in
a-bc.net
abyssmail.com
afrobacon.com
ag.us.to
agedmail.com
ajaxapp.net
akapost.com
akerd.com
aktiefmail.nl
alivance.com
amail4.me
ama-trade.de
ama-trans.de
amilegit.com
amiri.net
amiriindustries.com
anappthat.com
ano-mail.net
anonbox.net
anon-mail.de
anonmails.de
anonymail.dk
anonymbox.com
anonymousmail.org
anonymousspeech.com
antichef.com
antichef.net
antireg.com
antireg.ru
antispam.de
antispam24.de
antispammail.de
armyspy.com
artman-conception.com
asdasd.nl
asdasd.ru
atvclub.msk.ru
auti.st
avpa.nl
azmeil.tk
b2cmail.de
baxomale.ht.cx
beddly.com
beefmilk.com
big1.us
bigprofessor.so
bigstring.com
binkmail.com
bio-muesli.info
bio-muesli.net
blackmarket.to
bladesmail.net
bloatbox.com
blogmyway.org
blogos.com
bluebottle.com
bobmail.info
bodhi.lawlita.com
bofthew.com
bootybay.de
boun.cr
bouncr.com
boxformail.in
boximail.com
br.mintemail.com
brainonfire.net
breakthru.com
brefmail.com
brennendesreich.de
broadbandninja.com
bsnow.net
bspamfree.org
bu.mintemail.com
buffemail.com
bugmenever.com
bugmenot.com
bumpymail.com
bund.us
bundes-li.ga
burnthespam.info
burstmail.info
buymoreplays.com
buyusedlibrarybooks.org
byom.de
c2.hu
cachedot.net
cam4you.cc
card.zp.ua
casualdx.com
cc.liamria
cek.pm
cellurl.com
centermail.com
centermail.net
chammy.info
cheatmail.de
childsavetrust.org
chogmail.com
choicemail1.com
chong-mail.com
chong-mail.net
chong-mail.org
clixser.com
clrmail.com
cmail.com
cmail.net
cmail.org
cock.li
coieo.com
coldemail.info
consumerriot.com
cool.fr.nf
correo.blogos.net
cosmorph.com
courriel.fr.nf
courrieltemporaire.com
crapmail.org
crazymailing.com
cubiclink.com
cumallover.me
curryworld.de
cust.in
cuvox.de
d3p.dk
dacoolest.com
dandikmail.com
dayrep.com
dbunker.com
dcemail.com
deadaddress.com
deadchildren.org
deadfake.cf
deadfake.ga
deadfake.ml
deadfake.tk
deadspam.com
deagot.com
dealja.com
delikkt.de
despam.it
despammed.com
devnullmail.com
dfgh.net
dharmatel.net
dicksinhisan.us
dicksinmyan.us
digitalsanctuary.com
dingbone.com
discard.cf
discard.email
discard.ga
discard.gq
discard.ml
discard.tk
discardmail.com
discardmail.de
disposable.cf
disposable.ga
disposable.ml
disposableaddress.com
disposable-email.ml
disposableemailaddresses.com
disposableinbox.com
dispose.it
disposeamail.com
disposemail.com
dispostable.com
divermail.com
dm.w3internet.co.uk
dm.w3internet.co.ukexample.com
docmail.com
dodgeit.com
dodgit.com
dodgit.org
doiea.com
domozmail.com
donemail.ru
dontreg.com
dontsendmespam.de
dotman.de
dotmsg.com
drdrb.com
drdrb.net
dropcake.de
droplister.com
dropmail.me
dudmail.com
dumpandjunk.com
dump-email.info
dumpmail.de
dumpyemail.com
duskmail.com
e4ward.com
easytrashmail.com
edv.to
ee1.pl
ee2.pl
eelmail.com
einmalmail.de
einrot.com
einrot.de
eintagsmail.de
e-mail.com
email.net
e-mail.org
email60.com
emailage.cf
emailage.ga
emailage.gq
emailage.ml
emailage.tk
emaildienst.de
email-fake.cf
email-fake.ga
email-fake.gq
email-fake.ml
email-fake.tk
emailgo.de
emailias.com
emailigo.de
emailinfive.com
emaillime.com
emailmiser.com
emails.ga
emailsensei.com
emailspam.cf
emailspam.ga
emailspam.gq
emailspam.ml
emailspam.tk
emailtemporanea.com
emailtemporanea.net
emailtemporar.ro
emailtemporario.com.br
emailthe.net
emailtmp.com
emailto.de
emailwarden.com
emailx.at.hm
emailxfer.com
emailz.cf
emailz.ga
emailz.gq
emailz.ml
emeil.in
emeil.ir
emkei.cf
emkei.ga
emkei.gq
emkei.ml
emkei.tk
emz.net
enterto.com
ephemail.net
e-postkasten.com
e-postkasten.de
e-postkasten.eu
e-postkasten.info
ero-tube.org
etranquil.com
etranquil.net
etranquil.org
evopo.com
example.com
explodemail.com
express.net.ua
eyepaste.com
facebook-email.cf
facebook-email.ga
facebook-email.ml
facebookmail.gq
facebookmail.ml
faecesmail.me
fakedemail.com
fakeinbox.cf
fakeinbox.com
fakeinbox.ga
fakeinbox.ml
fakeinbox.tk
fakeinformation.com
fake-mail.cf
fakemail.fr
fake-mail.ga
fake-mail.ml
fakemailgenerator.com
fakemailz.com
fammix.com
fansworldwide.de
fantasymail.de
fastacura.com
fastchevy.com
fastchrysler.com
fastermail.com
fastkawasaki.com
fastmail.fm
fastmazda.com
fastmitsubishi.com
fastnissan.com
fastsubaru.com
fastsuzuki.com
fasttoyota.com
fastyamaha.com
fatflap.com
fdfdsfds.com
fightallspam.com
film-blog.biz
filzmail.com
fivemail.de
fixmail.tk
fizmail.com
fleckens.hu
flurred.com
flyspam.com
fly-ts.de
footard.com
forgetmail.com
fornow.eu
fr33mail.info
frapmail.com
freecoolemail.com
free-email.cf
free-email.ga
freeletter.me
freemail.ms
freemails.cf
freemails.ga
freemails.ml
freundin.ru
friendlymail.co.uk
front14.org
fuckingduh.com
fuckmail.me
fudgerub.com
fux0ringduh.com
fyii.de
garbagemail.org
garliclife.com
garrifulio.mailexpire.com
gawab.com
gehensiemirnichtaufdensack.de
gelitik.in
geschent.biz
get1mail.com
get2mail.fr
getairmail.cf
getairmail.com
getairmail.ga
getairmail.gq
getairmail.ml
getairmail.tk
get-mail.cf
get-mail.ga
get-mail.ml
get-mail.tk
getmails.eu
getonemail.com
getonemail.net
ghosttexter.de
giantmail.de
girlsundertheinfluence.com
gishpuppy.com
gmal.com
gmial.com
gmx.com
goat.si
goemailgo.com
gomail.in
gorillaswithdirtyarmpits.com
gotmail.com
gotmail.net
gotmail.org
gotti.otherinbox.com
gowikibooks.com
gowikicampus.com
gowikicars.com
gowikifilms.com
gowikigames.com
gowikimusic.com
gowikinetwork.com
gowikitravel.com
gowikitv.com
grandmamail.com
grandmasmail.com
great-host.in
greensloth.com
grr.la
gsrv.co.uk
guerillamail.biz
guerillamail.com
guerillamail.net
guerillamail.org
guerillamailblock.com
guerrillamail.biz
guerrillamail.com
guerrillamail.de
guerrillamail.info
guerrillamail.net
guerrillamail.org
guerrillamailblock.com
gustr.com
h.mintemail.com
h8s.org
hacccc.com
haltospam.com
harakirimail.com
hartbot.de
hatespam.org
hat-geld.de
herp.in
hidemail.de
hidzz.com
hmamail.com
hochsitze.com
hooohush.ai
hopemail.biz
horsefucker.org
hotmai.com
hot-mail.cf
hot-mail.ga
hot-mail.gq
hot-mail.ml
hot-mail.tk
hotmial.com
hotpop.com
huajiachem.cn
hulapla.de
humaility.com
hush.ai
hush.com
hushmail.com
hushmail.me
i2pmail.org
ieatspam.eu
ieatspam.info
ieh-mail.de
ignoremail.com
ihateyoualot.info
iheartspam.org
ikbenspamvrij.nl
imails.info
imgof.com
imgv.de
imstations.com
inbax.tk
inbox.si
inbox2.info
inboxalias.com
inboxclean.com
inboxclean.org
inboxdesign.me
inboxed.im
inboxed.pw
inboxstore.me
incognitomail.com
incognitomail.net
incognitomail.org
infocom.zp.ua
insorg-mail.info
instantemailaddress.com
instant-mail.de
iozak.com
ip6.li
ipoo.org
irish2me.com
iroid.com
is.af
iwantmyname.com
iwi.net
jetable.com
jetable.fr.nf
jetable.net
jetable.org
jnxjn.com
jourrapide.com
jsrsolutions.com
junk.to
junk1e.com
junkmail.ga
junkmail.gq
k2-herbal-incenses.com
kasmail.com
kaspop.com
keepmymail.com
killmail.com
killmail.net
kir.ch.tc
klassmaster.com
klassmaster.net
klzlk.com
kmhow.com
kostenlosemailadresse.de
koszmail.pl
kulturbetrieb.info
kurzepost.de
l33r.eu
lackmail.net
lags.us
landmail.co
lastmail.co
lavabit.com
lawlita.com
letthemeatspam.com
lhsdv.com
lifebyfood.com
link2mail.net
linuxmail.so
litedrop.com
llogin.ru
loadby.us
login-email.cf
login-email.ga
login-email.ml
login-email.tk
lol.com
lol.ovpn.to
lolfreak.net
lookugly.com
lopl.co.cc
lortemail.dk
losemymail.com
lovebitco.in
lovemeleaveme.com
loves.dicksinhisan.us
loves.dicksinmyan.us
lr7.us
lr78.com
lroid.com
luckymail.org
lukop.dk
luv2.us
m21.cc
m4ilweb.info
ma1l.bij.pl
maboard.com
mac.hush.com
mail.by
mail.me
mail.mezimages.net
mail.ru
mail.zp.ua
mail114.net
mail1a.de
mail21.cc
mail2rss.org
mail2world.com
mail333.com
mail4trash.com
mailbidon.com
mailbiz.biz
mailblocks.com
mailbucket.org
mailcat.biz
mailcatch.com
mailde.de
mailde.info
maildrop.cc
maildrop.cf
maildrop.ga
maildrop.gq
maildrop.ml
maildu.de
maileater.com
mailed.in
maileimer.de
mailexpire.com
mailfa.tk
mail-filter.com
mailforspam.com
mailfree.ga
mailfree.gq
mailfree.ml
mailfreeonline.com
mailguard.me
mailhazard.com
mailhazard.us
mailhz.me
mailimate.com
mailin8r.com
mailinater.com
mailinator.com
mailinator.gq
mailinator.net
mailinator.org
mailinator.us
mailinator2.com
mailincubator.com
mailismagic.com
mailita.tk
mailjunk.cf
mailjunk.ga
mailjunk.gq
mailjunk.ml
mailjunk.tk
mailme.gq
mailme.ir
mailme.lv
mailme24.com
mailmetrash.com
mailmoat.com
mailms.com
mailnator.com
mailnesia.com
mailnull.com
mailorg.org
mailpick.biz
mailquack.com
mailrock.biz
mailsac.com
mailscrap.com
mailseal.de
mailshell.com
mailsiphon.com
mailslapping.com
mailslite.com
mailtemp.info
mail-temporaire.fr
mailtome.de
mailtothis.com
mailtrash.net
mailtv.net
mailtv.tv
mailwithyou.com
mailzilla.com
mailzilla.org
makemetheking.com
malahov.de
manifestgenerator.com
manybrain.com
mbx.cc
mega.zik.dj
meinspamschutz.de
meltmail.com
messagebeamer.de
mezimages.net
mierdamail.com
migmail.pl
migumail.com
ministry-of-silly-walks.de
mintemail.com
misterpinball.de
mjukglass.nu
mmmmail.com
moakt.com
mobi.web.id
mobileninja.co.uk
moburl.com
moncourrier.fr.nf
monemail.fr.nf
monmail.fr.nf
monumentmail.com
ms9.mailslite.com
msa.minsmail.com
msb.minsmail.com
msg.mailslite.com
mt2009.com
mt2014.com
mt2015.com
muchomail.com
mx0.wwwnew.eu
my10minutemail.com
mycard.net.ua
mycleaninbox.net
myemailboxy.com
mymail-in.net
mynetstore.de
mypacks.net
mypartyclip.de
myphantomemail.com
mysamp.de
myspaceinc.com
myspaceinc.net
myspaceinc.org
myspacepimpedup.com
myspamless.com
mytempemail.com
mytempmail.com
mythrashmail.net
mytrashmail.com
nabuma.com
national.shitposting.agency
naver.com
neomailbox.com
nepwk.com
nervmich.net
nervtmich.net
netmails.com
netmails.net
netzidiot.de
neverbox.com
nevermail.de
nice-4u.com
nigge.rs
nincsmail.hu
nmail.cf
nnh.com
noblepioneer.com
nobugmail.com
nobulk.com
nobuma.com
noclickemail.com
nogmailspam.info
nomail.pw
nomail.xl.cx
nomail2me.com
nomorespamemails.com
nonspam.eu
nonspammer.de
noref.in
nospam.wins.com.br
no-spam.ws
nospam.ze.tc
nospam4.us
nospamfor.us
nospammail.net
nospamthanks.info
notmailinator.com
notsharingmy.info
nowhere.org
nowmymail.com
ntlhelp.net
nullbox.info
nurfuerspam.de
nus.edu.sg
nwldx.com
o2.co.uk
o2.pl
objectmail.com
obobbo.com
odaymail.com
odnorazovoe.ru
ohaaa.de
omail.pro
oneoffemail.com
oneoffmail.com
onewaymail.com
onlatedotcom.info
online.ms
oopi.org
opayq.com
ordinaryamerican.net
otherinbox.com
ourklips.com
outlawspam.com
ovpn.to
owlpic.com
pancakemail.com
paplease.com
pcusers.otherinbox.com
pepbot.com
pfui.ru
phentermine-mortgages-texas-holdem.biz
pimpedupmyspace.com
pjjkp.com
plexolan.de
poczta.onet.pl
politikerclub.de
poofy.org
pookmail.com
postonline.me
powered.name
privacy.net
privatdemail.net
privy-mail.com
privymail.de
privy-mail.de
proxymail.eu
prtnx.com
prtz.eu
punkass.com
put2.net
putthisinyourspamdatabase.com
pwrby.com
qasti.com
qisdo.com
qisoa.com
qoika.com
qq.com
quickinbox.com
quickmail.nl
rcpt.at
rcs.gaggle.net
reallymymail.com
realtyalerts.ca
receiveee.com
recode.me
recursor.net
recyclemail.dk
redchan.it
regbypass.com
regbypass.comsafe-mail.net
rejectmail.com
reliable-mail.com
remail.cf
remail.ga
rhyta.com
rklips.com
rmqkr.net
royal.net
rppkn.com
rtrtr.com
s0ny.net
safe-mail.net
safersignup.de
safetymail.info
safetypost.de
sandelf.de
saynotospams.com
scatmail.com
schafmail.de
schmeissweg.tk
schrott-email.de
secmail.pw
secretemail.de
secure-mail.biz
secure-mail.cc
selfdestructingmail.com
selfdestructingmail.org
sendspamhere.com
senseless-entertainment.com
server.ms
services391.com
sharklasers.com
shieldedmail.com
shieldemail.com
shiftmail.com
shitmail.me
shitmail.org
shitware.nl
shmeriously.com
shortmail.net
shut.name
shut.ws
sibmail.com
sify.com
sina.cn
sina.com
sinnlos-mail.de
siteposter.net
skeefmail.com
sky-ts.de
slapsfromlastnight.com
slaskpost.se
slave-auctions.net
slopsbox.com
slushmail.com
smaakt.naar.gravel
smapfree24.com
smapfree24.de
smapfree24.eu
smapfree24.info
smapfree24.org
smashmail.de
smellfear.com
snakemail.com
sneakemail.com
sneakmail.de
snkmail.com
sofimail.com
sofortmail.de
sofort-mail.de
sogetthis.com
sohu.com
solvemail.info
soodomail.com
soodonims.com
spam.la
spam.su
spam4.me
spamail.de
spamarrest.com
spamavert.com
spam-be-gone.com
spambob.com
spambob.net
spambob.org
spambog.com
spambog.de
spambog.net
spambog.ru
spambooger.com
spambox.info
spambox.irishspringrealty.com
spambox.org
spambox.us
spamcannon.com
spamcannon.net
spamcero.com
spamcon.org
spamcorptastic.com
spamcowboy.com
spamcowboy.net
spamcowboy.org
spamday.com
spamdecoy.net
spamex.com
spamfighter.cf
spamfighter.ga
spamfighter.gq
spamfighter.ml
spamfighter.tk
spamfree.eu
spamfree24.com
spamfree24.de
spamfree24.eu
spamfree24.info
spamfree24.net
spamfree24.org
spamgoes.in
spamgourmet.com
spamgourmet.net
spamgourmet.org
spamherelots.com
spamhereplease.com
spamhole.com
spamify.com
spaminator.de
spamkill.info
spaml.com
spaml.de
spammotel.com
spamobox.com
spamoff.de
spamsalad.in
spamslicer.com
spamspot.com
spamstack.net
spamthis.co.uk
spamthisplease.com
spamtrail.com
spamtroll.net
speed.1s.fr
spoofmail.de
squizzy.de
sry.li
ssoia.com
startkeys.com
stinkefinger.net
stop-my-spam.cf
stop-my-spam.com
stop-my-spam.ga
stop-my-spam.ml
stop-my-spam.tk
stuffmail.de
suioe.com
super-auswahl.de
supergreatmail.com
supermailer.jp
superplatyna.com
superrito.com
superstachel.de
suremail.info
sweetxxx.de
tafmail.com
tagyourself.com
talkinator.com
tapchicuoihoi.com
techemail.com
techgroup.me
teewars.org
teleworm.com
teleworm.us
temp.emeraldwebmail.com
tempail.com
tempalias.com
tempemail.biz
tempemail.co.za
tempemail.com
tempe-mail.com
tempemail.net
tempimbox.com
tempinbox.co.uk
tempinbox.com
tempmail.eu
tempmail.it
temp-mail.org
temp-mail.ru
tempmail2.com
tempmaildemo.com
tempmailer.com
tempmailer.de
tempomail.fr
temporarily.de
temporarioemail.com.br
temporaryemail.net
temporaryemail.us
temporaryforwarding.com
temporaryinbox.com
temporarymailaddress.com
tempthe.net
tempymail.com
tfwno.gf
thanksnospam.info
thankyou2010.com
thc.st
thecloudindex.com
thelimestones.com
thisisnotmyrealemail.com
thismail.net
thrma.com
throam.com
throwawayemailaddress.com
throwawaymail.com
tijdelijkmailadres.nl
tilien.com
tittbit.in
tizi.com
tmail.com
tmailinator.com
toiea.com
tokem.co
toomail.biz
topcoolemail.com
topfreeemail.com
topranklist.de
tormail.net
tormail.org
tradermail.info
trash2009.com
trash2010.com
trash2011.com
trash-amil.com
trashcanmail.com
trashdevil.com
trashdevil.de
trashemail.de
trashinbox.com
trashmail.at
trash-mail.at
trash-mail.cf
trashmail.com
trash-mail.com
trashmail.de
trash-mail.de
trash-mail.ga
trash-mail.gq
trashmail.me
trash-mail.ml
trashmail.net
trashmail.org
trash-mail.tk
trashmail.ws
trashmailer.com
trashymail.com
trashymail.net
trayna.com
trbvm.com
trialmail.de
trickmail.net
trillianpro.com
tryalert.com
turual.com
twinmail.de
tyldd.com
ubismail.net
uggsrock.com
umail.net
upliftnow.com
uplipht.com
uroid.com
us.af
uyhip.com
valemail.net
venompen.com
verticalscope.com
veryrealemail.com
veryrealmail.com
vidchart.com
viditag.com
viewcastmedia.com
viewcastmedia.net
viewcastmedia.org
vipmail.name
vipmail.pw
viralplays.com
vistomail.com
vomoto.com
vpn.st
vsimcard.com
vubby.com
vztc.com
walala.org
walkmail.net
wants.dicksinhisan.us
wants.dicksinmyan.us
wasteland.rfc822.org
watchfull.net
watch-harry-potter.com
webemail.me
webm4il.info
webuser.in
wegwerfadresse.de
wegwerfemail.com
wegwerfemail.de
wegwerf-email.de
weg-werf-email.de
wegwerfemail.net
wegwerf-email.net
wegwerfemail.org
wegwerf-email-addressen.de
wegwerfemailadresse.com
wegwerf-email-adressen.de
wegwerf-emails.de
wegwerfmail.de
wegwerfmail.info
wegwerfmail.net
wegwerfmail.org
wegwerpmailadres.nl
wegwrfmail.de
wegwrfmail.net
wegwrfmail.org
wetrainbayarea.com
wetrainbayarea.org
wh4f.org
whatiaas.com
whatpaas.com
whatsaas.com
whopy.com
whyspam.me
wickmail.net
wilemail.com
willhackforfood.biz
willselfdestruct.com
winemaven.info
wmail.cf
wolfsmail.tk
writeme.us
wronghead.com
wuzup.net
wuzupmail.net
www.e4ward.com
www.gishpuppy.com
www.mailinator.com
wwwnew.eu
x.ip6.li
xagloo.co
xagloo.com
xemaps.com
xents.com
xmail.com
xmaily.com
xoxox.cc
xoxy.net
xxtreamcam.com
xyzfree.net
yandex.com
yanet.me
yapped.net
yeah.net
yep.it
yogamaven.com
yomail.info
yopmail.com
yopmail.fr
yopmail.gq
yopmail.net
youmail.ga
youmailr.com
yourdomain.com
you-spam.com
ypmail.webarnak.fr.eu.org
yuurok.com
yxzx.net
z1p.biz
za.com
zebins.com
zebins.eu
zehnminuten.de
zehnminutenmail.de
zetmail.com
zippymail.info
zoaxe.com
zoemail.com
zoemail.net
zoemail.org
zomg.info
```

And if not this enough, send a confirmation mail to your user